# MKMapView annotation image changes to pin on click

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

Im my iphone mapview application when i click on the annotation images it get change into pin. Can anyone please tell me how can i correct it?

My idea is to display a image instead of custom pin, even though it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a annotation this delegate will be called

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
//I think here you will be adding a annotation(my assumption)
[mapView addAnnotation:yourAnnotation];
//This will call viewForAnnotation again
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
//If you didnt specify the a image for the annotation the default pin image will be assigned here..
}
```

If my assumption is wrong then post your code here related annotations, So you can get better answers

Comment: How to call the mapview viewforannotaion method on a button click method in iphone